# Do we need multiple history tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, we have [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history), [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history), and [game-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history) on the main site, with 17, 3, and 1 questions, respectively. We've also had other history tags at times, such as [cosplay-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay-history) on [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/who-was-the-first-cosplayer), which is now tagged (somewhat incorrectly) as [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history). In principle, we could also get [light-novel-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel-history), [visual-novel-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-novel-history), [voice-acting-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-acting-history), and presumably others.

Is there a benefit to having separate tags for these? I can see why [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) and [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production) would require somewhat different knowledge to answer in, but in the case of history I think the same people would tend to be experts on both, and there's little benefit to splitting them up.

As such, I propose merging these three tags into one [history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag which covers all questions about history within the context of anime and manga. [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history) and [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history) could be made synonyms of this so that newcomers have an easier time finding this tag.

Answer (score 5):

I agree, and looks like the community agrees on it too. If no objection is raised in say, 2 days, I'll merge the tags and update here.

Comment: I personally think there is no harm in leaving them alone. Tag merging can be done quickly, while it is harder to separate them out. How about leaving them alone for a while, to see how bad it becomes?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Post it as an answer on this question, explain why you think it should be left alone.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be good for browsing/searching. Since [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) and [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) are banned, I imagine these multiple history tags would add another level to the categorization. However, I am not sure whether it is useful in long term.

I don't think there is any harm leaving it there for a while. Tag merging can be done quickly, but it is harder to separate them out later. For favorite (following) purpose, people can use `*history` to follow all history tags.

Comment: We've had these split for a while already. Has this actually been helpful? I personally haven't found any use for it, and there's no one following either of the two less-common tags so it's hard to believe that anyone else has. If there's evidence that it's helping someone, then it might be worth keeping them separate, but I don't see any such evidence.

Comment: @LoganM: The number of follows is somewhat proportional to the number of questions. Less common tags are less likely to be followed. I would imagine that these specific tags adds another level to the categorization (since anime and manga tags are banned).