# Merging history tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We had a discussion about this 2 years ago in 
[Do we need multiple history tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/do-we-need-multiple-history-tags)

But I think it's time to review this, we have 2 [game-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history) questions, 18 [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history) questions (10 of which are also tagged with anime) and 62 [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history) questions.

As @Logan_M said before, there'll be a lot of overlap of this knowledge and that's shown with the overlap of tags as mentioned above. It also might lead to the creation of many other tags that don't fit exactly in those categories - light novels for example.

we removed [cosplay-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay-history) before and haven't really missed it. Shall we merge the tags into one all encompassing [history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag?

Comment: I think we forgot about this... D: sorrie

Comment: Personally, I see no problem with merging them all into an encompassing "history" tag.

Comment: The issue I take with it is that there are people who are experts in [manga-history], but not [anime-history], and vice-versa.

Comment: I don't know if there's that much of a knowledge difference - many of the main figures & events in manga are also present in anime

Comment: Just wondering, but is game-history on-topic here? Shouldn't that be moved to Arquade.SE?

Comment: @PeterRaeves That looks like a badly-named tag that we want to get rid of. The three questions tagged with [tag:game-history] are better off without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [nhahtdh's comment](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/do-we-need-multiple-history-tags#comment1086_582) in the linked meta post, tag merging can be done quickly, but undoing a tag merge can be cumbersome. To be on the safe side, unless there is evidence that keeping the tags separate causes harm, I side with not merging the history tags.

Furthermore, [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history) is to [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history) as [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) is to [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), and I don't think many people will be eager to merge the latter two tags under [production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production). I imagine there are people who are only interested in the history of anime (maybe they only watch anime and don't read many manga) and vice versa, so even though the two histories are closely tied to each other, I argue that it is useful to separate them. Also, as キルア said in the comment, there are people who are experts in [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history), but not [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history), and vice versa.

Having separate history tags for different media also scales better. If you worry that this might lead to the creation of many other tags that don't fit exactly in those categories, we can maybe tag them all under [other-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-history).

Comment: +1 Considering one of my professors at university is an expert on manga history (going back to the first scrolls), but knows little of anime, I see a great reason to keep them apart.